# Merge three or more dataframes into single and keep null values using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have three text files like this:

file1.txt

```
f_name

Nikc

Jack
Fro
Singwa
```

file2.txt

```
l_name


Kolo
Polo
Dolo
```

file3.txt

```
d

Sonio
Polio
Kolio
Lass
```

I have converted each file into dataframes using

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1.txt)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2.txt)
df3 = pd.read_csv(file3.txt)
```

Now when I merge this into single dataframe, it skips all blank spaces

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
print(df.head())

Output returns like this:
f_name  l_name  d
Nikc    Kolo    Sonio
Jack    Polo    Polio
Fro     Dolo    Kolio
Singwa          Lass
```

But I need Output like this:

```
f_name  l_name  d
Nikc                 
                Sonio
Jack    Kolo    Polio
Fro     Polo    Kolio
Singwa  Dolo    Lass
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong, or what is correct way doing this

Comment: Please feel free to accept the answer by ticking if you feel it was the most appropriate solution to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read your csv with skip_blank_lines = False, you should be OK.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(1.txt,skip_blank_lines =False)


Output:
f_name

Nikc

Jack
Fro
Singwa
```

Comment: The issue is you went personal

Comment: You decided that there is an issue, the only thing I said is your solution doesn't work and your output is wrong... You decided to take it personal and to do an issue with it. I have no issue my friend. ;)

Comment: @JonathanGagne : What amazed me was that you had a very different solution before the one you have now; and my solution although small had been upvoted and moved forward by the person who had posed the question..and then you go onto pick the main idea behind my solution and just frame it nicely and post it..
Anyways..cheers

Comment: What about your `file1.txt` instead `'file1.txt'`, the `ignore_index=True` where he lost his headers, or the `df.iloc[1:]` for the spare row on the top? I mean yes, we got both of us the `skip_blank_lines =False` but you missed 3 though... Moreover, you said that the output was that. Poor guy, he can try this out all night long, there is no quote.... Well, then, I told your mistake, you downvote me, and this is where you call it cheers. Honestly, I do respect developer and their ego, so as I said, I have zero issue ;) Peace my friend!